# How do I edit an IEnumerable<T> with ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, ienumerable, asp.net-mvc-3

Given the following types

```
public class SomeValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class SomeModel
{
    public string SomeProp1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeProp2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomeValue> MyData { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create an edit form for the type `SomeModel` which would contain the usual text fields for `SomeProp1` and `SomeProp2` and then a table containing a text field for each `SomeValue` in the `SomeModel.MyData` collection.

How is this done? How do the values get bound back to the model?

I currently have a form displaying a text field for each value but they all have the same name and same Id. This is obviously not valid HTML and will prevent MVC from mapping the values back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would do it using Editor Templates. This way the framework will take care of everything (from properly naming the input fields to properly binding the values back in the post action).

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // In the GET action populate your model somehow
        // and render the form so that the user can edit it
        var model = new SomeModel
        {
            SomeProp1 = "prop1",
            SomeProp2 = "prop1",
            MyData = new[] 
            {
                new SomeValue { Id = 1, Value = 123 },
                new SomeValue { Id = 2, Value = 456 },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
    {
        // Here the model will be properly bound
        // with the values that the user modified
        // in the form so you could perform some action
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.aspx`):

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

    Prop1: <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProp1) %><br/>
    Prop2: <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProp2) %><br/>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyData) %><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

And finally the Editor Template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/SomeValue.ascx`) which will be automatically invoked for each element of the `MyData` collection:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyApp.Models.SomeValue>" %>
<div>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id) %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value) %>
</div>
```

Comment: Heh, I guess I won't post it now because you're answer is already better :) I didn't know you could bind lists that easily though. Thanks

Comment: for MVC3 isn't it better to use Razor?

Answer (score 1):

`IList` implements IEnumerable so you could modify your model like so:

```
public class SomeModel {
    public string SomeProp1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeProp2 { get; set; }
    public IList<SomeValue> MyData { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the `IModelBinder` interface to create a binder for your specific model. There are a couple ways to do it. You can create an `EditorFor` cshtml for the model which will loop through your `SomeValue` list and output appropriate ids and what not. Then, in your `ModelBinder` implementation your would then read through your ids and bind them appropriately. I can post a working sample in a while.

Comment: When the form is submitted, will the ViewEngine take care of binding the data back to the correct elements in the Collection?

Comment: You know what's really weird...I could have **sworn** this question asked something different...I think I was reading two questions at the same time and replied to the wrong one...I'm going to change my answer