# Loop through the properties in a model in C# , mVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have view, whose I will be rending it from html helper functions.

```
@using PartyBiz.Models.Objects
@model IEnumerable<Person>
@Html.PageStructureEntity(Model)
```

I wrote the below sample method to return content to view:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString PageStructureEntity(this HtmlHelper helper, Person m)
    {
        TagBuilder
              stdDiv = MvcUtils.GetStdDiv(); //Parent Site Part Version's container


        switch (m.FirstName.GetType().FullName)
        {
            case "System.String":
                TagBuilder input = MvcUtils.GetStdInput();
                input.Attributes.Add("value", m.FirstName);
                stdDiv.InnerHtml = input.ToString();
                break;

            default:
                return null;
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(stdDiv.ToString());
    }
```

I have to loop through every model object in IEnumerable and every property in that model object, render the inputs or checkboxes or datetimes as per their type.

My problem is I am doing it in a pretty standard style.
Is there any best approach for this to write the code better, something using generics or built helper functions?

Your suggestions helps a lot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

This will render all the default editor templates for your models properties.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233832/how-do-i-edit-an-ienumerablet-with-asp-net-mvc-3) for more details

Comment: EditorForModel() doesnt work for us. we have to use our own custom textboxes dropdowns etc., also the view should be generic it should be able to accept any model and should allow it to edit.